# PHP how to add Prefix to variable

Tags: php, variables, prefix

I'm looking to add a prefix to a variable I created. 
The variable is a number from 1 to 999. 
Lets call the variable `$withoutPrefix`. I want all variables to become prefix-1 to prefix-999. 
I found str_pad does the trick but you have to submit a desired number of total characters making the solution unsuitable for variables with multiple different number of digits.

Example of my current non ideal solution:

```
<?php $withPrefix = str_pad($withoutPrefix,7, 'post-' ,STR_PAD_LEFT); ?>
```

it gives me prefix-10 and prefix-p7. Not ideal.

ps.
While typing my question: The problem would be solved if my variable started at 100 and ranged to 999 (something I can actually do). But i still don't like the rigid non flexible solution.

Comment: is the number to be generated too? Where does the number come from? Does 1 have to be 001 ?

Comment: One day, PHP will support arrays, and we won't need to come up with workrounds like this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$withPrefix = "prefix-" . $withoutPrefix;
```

Comment: Neat simple solution. Shows there is a lot for me to learn about php.  Thanks for the quick response.